# How can I update state as an array of objects without overriding previous state

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to update setTopic without overriding previous state. But I am getting `topic is not iterable` error.

What I tried?
I tried looking a different examples on stack overflow, But still couldn't figure out how to append updated state without losing previous state.

Also, which is a better way to save multiple topics :  an array of objects, simply objects or simply array?

```
const AddTopic = (props) => {
  const { subjectName } = props;
  const [topic, setTopic] = useState([
    {
      topics: [
        {
          id: Math.random().toString(36).substr(2, 7),
          topicName: "topic name",
          subject: subjectName,
        },
      ],
    },
  ]);

  const addTopicHandler = () => {

    setTopic(
      [...topic].map((item) => {
        return {
          ...item,
          id: Math.random().toString(36).substr(2, 7),
          topicName: "another topic name",
          subject: subjectName,
        };
      })
    );
  };
  console.log(topic);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Instead of the child component using state [lift the state](https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html) to a parent component, and then just create dumb `Topic` components from the state.
2. Rename your state. Call it `topics`, and the update function `setTopics`. Initialise it as an array, not an array containing one object containing an array.
3. You can't immediately log an updated state. You need to use [`useEffect`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useeffect) to watch for changes in state, and then log something.

```js
const { useEffect, useState } = React;

// Topic component - just gets handed the
// subject (in this example) in the props
function Topic({ subject, category }) {
  return <div>{subject}: {category}</div>;
}

function Example() {

  // Initialise `topics` as an array
  const [ topics, setTopics ] = useState([]);

  // When `topics` is updated, log the updated state
  useEffect(() => console.log(JSON.stringify(topics)), [topics]);

  // Helper function that maps over the state and
  // produces an array of topics
  function getTopics() {
    return topics.map(topic => {
      const { subject, category } = topic;
      return (
        <Topic
          subject={subject}
          category={category}
        />
      );
    });
  }

  // Helper function to add a new topic object
  // to the topics state
  function addTopic() {
    const obj = { subject: 'Math', category: 'Fish' };
    setTopics([...topics, obj ]);
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <div>{getTopics()}</div>
      <button onClick={addTopic}>Add topic</button>
    </div>
  );
};

ReactDOM.render(
  <Example />,
  document.getElementById('react')
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.2/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.2/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="react"></div>
```

Comment: Here's what I want to do. I have subjects e.g., Mathematics, biology etc. When a user click a subject `subjectName` is updated. Now, I want to add topics related to this subectName. That's why I have an array of objects that contains subjectName. How can I use only array to store id, topicName as well as subjectName. there will be multiple such topics. What is the best way to do this.

Comment: You're making things too complicated. Just add new topics to the array that have properties that define them: `{ subject: 'Math', topic: 'Algebra' }` or `{ subject: 'Biology, topic: 'Fish' }`. You can then filter on those array objects however you want.

Answer (score 0):

Try to replace `[...topic].map` with `[...topic.topics].map`.

**edit**
Sorry, I didn't see that the `topic` itself is an arr of objs, so it should be: `[...topic[0].topics].map`.

Comment: I already tried it. TypeError: topic.topics is not iterable.

Comment: doesn't work. Same problem.